# Angular2 ngNoForm and also do angular form validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a legacy backend server that processes form data as request parameters. 
We are putting angular2 on the front end. I want to submit the angular2 form so that all fields go as request parameters so that the legacy backend doesn't have to be changed. 
To do this I have :

```
<form  ngNoForm action="http://localhost/config/api/v1/angular/submit" target="_blank" method="POST">
```

But I also want to use the angular2 form validation on the submit button:

```
<form #f="ngForm" ngNoForm action="http://localhost/config/api/v1/angular/submit" target="_blank" method="POST">
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.form.valid" class="small round">Submit</button>
```

However this does not work - angular2 complains about having #f="ngForm" when ngNoForm is declared.

Is there any way to be able to do angular2 form validations as usual, and also submit the form as regular request parameters?

Comment: I am using ReactiveForms along with an AJAX request to achieve this.  I have no experience with using `ngNoForm`.  I add my request parameters to an array of strings, join them like `arr.join('&')` and the encode it with `encodeURI(body)`. There's definitely more to it than this, but this is the gist of organizing the form data.  In your TS. If this is something that's possible for you to do with your legacy app, I can post up a more detailed answer.

Comment: Unfortunately since the whole form is metadata driven, I don't have an idea of which fields are on the page. I guess I could figure out which fields are on the page using javascript and then implement the solution you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Force submit using pure JS, this worked for me:

```html
<form ngNoForm [formGroup]="myForm" action="http://test.local/process_post.php" target="_blank" method="POST">
    <input formControlName="alpha" name="alpha"/>
    <input formControlName="beta" name="beta"/>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" onclick="submit()">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't want to use the formGroup, i.e I want to use [ngModel] way of binding since my form is very dynamic based on data sent by the server, and only template driven forms i.e using ngModel works out well for us.

Comment: is it possible to use a button outside the form tags to submit with ngNoForm