# Angular 2 - Updating hidden form fields and then POSTing to external page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular

I have an Angular2 application which at some point needs to send the user to a page on an external service with a POST request.

Basically the flow should be as follows

- User clicks on a button
- Default form submit event is intercepted and prevented
- API call is performed to set up some stuff on the backend and retrieve some values to pass to the external service
- Some hidden form fields are populated with data retrieved from the API
- Form submit is then fired

As far as I can ascertain from posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233966/angular2-how-to-postredirect-form-with-action-on-external-site), there is no way of performing a "POST to external page"-type action in Angular, and one must instead override Angular's form handling with `ngNoForm` and allow the browser to handle it as a regular POST.

So, currently, I have a template like this:

```
<form ngNoForm (submit)="proceedToService($event)" method="POST" action="https://some-service.com/etc">
 <input type="hidden" name="token" [value]="someToken">
 <button type="submit">Proceed to external service</button>
</form>
```

And in the component I have this:

```
public someToken:string="";

proceedToService($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.apiHandler.doSomeStuff().subscribe(
        (someStuff) => {
            this.someToken = someStuff.token;
            $event.target.submit();
        }
    );
}
```

(`doSomeStuff` returns an Observable)

The problem I have with this approach is that the submit event seemingly gets fired before the value has been populated in the DOM, meaning the `token` field is empty in the POST request.

I was able to get it to work by wrapping the `$event.target.submit();` in a setTimeout call as follows:

`setTimeout(() => {$event.target.submit()}, 1000);`

but this feels like a super hacky way of doing it, could still fail anyway (what if it takes more than 1 second to update?) and is hard to test.

So is there any better way of achieving this? Ideally what I'd want to do is watch for the hidden input's value to actually be updated in the DOM and then fire the submit at that point. But so far I've been unable to find a way of doing this - ngModel binding for example does not support hidden fields.

I am very new to the Angular world and Angular2 in particular, so I may be approaching this from entirely the wrong angle, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using template reference variable and button type="button" combination.

```
<form ngNoForm #extForm method="POST" action="https://some-service.com/etc">  
 <button type="button" (click)="proceedToService(extForm)">External Service</button>
</form>
```

Typescript function

```
proceedToService(frm) {
    this.apiHandler.doSomeStuff().subscribe(
      (someStuff) => {        
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "hidden";
        input.name = "token";
        input.value = someStuff.token;;
        frm.appendChild(input);
        frm.submit();
      }
    );
  }
```

I hope this would help you

Answer (score 1):

I found a potential solution to this using `AfterViewChecked`, like so:

```
private pendingEvent;

proceedToService($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.apiHandler.doSomeStuff().subscribe(
        (someStuff) => {
            this.someToken = someStuff.token;
            this.pendingEvent = $event;
        }
    );
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if ( this.pendingEvent ) {
        this.pendingEvent.target.submit();
        this.pendingEvent = null;
    }
}
```

This seems to do what I'm looking for - since `ngAfterViewChecked` is called after the view is checked, and the view is checked after it's updated (I assume?)  the values are populated correctly at this point.

Again in my unfamiliarity with Angular I'm not sure if this is the best solution or even a viable solution in practice, but it at least "feels" better than using setTimeout...